# How do I have a child webpage receive a variable value from a parent webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For my school project I'm creating a mockup cinema website that has ticket booking service. Currently I'm trying to create the seat selection part.

I've successfully done that, and how the code detects if a seat has been selected is a Boolean value. (e.g. if they selected seat A1, a variable named "A1" will be set to true), now the only part left is to transfer the selection details users have selected to a popup webpage where they fill in their "payment" details. How do I exactly transfer variable values to a child webpage? Is a php file needed? I'm a noob at php so some guidance is appreciated.

I've been searching this technique for a while online(inc. stack overflow), but I couldn't find any right code that is right for my situation

```
<html>
<body>
The on/off button:
<button onclick="press_button"><img id="button" src="on.png" style="width:100px"></button>

<BR>
The button that opens a new webpage:
<button onclick="confirm()"> Confirm</button>


<script language="JavaScript">
var i=0, status;
function press_button(){
i++;
if(i%2 == 1){
document.getElementById('button').src='off.png';
status=true
}
else
document.getElementById('button').src='on.png';
status=false
}
//function that changes the look of the button when it is on/off and records down whether it is on/off
function confirm(){
window.open("confirm.html")
//opens a new webpage
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

For simplicity, I've made a simple web page that has an on/off button, and I'd like to have a confirm button that opens a new page and displays a text message depending on the status of the on/off button. Can anyone teach me how to do that?

Comment: From my understanding of your case, you may need to create a form with select tag and send those values to an modal form that user fills in their payment details. PHP can be use to receive those details from the form and send it to database.

Comment: Take note that many browsers block popups. I suggest creating a DIV overlay with the payment form. That way, you’re still on the same page so you have access to all the variables. To process the form and payment safely, you still need php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JS alone, but there are many other approaches too.

```
<body>
  <input type='text' value='defaultParamValue'>
  <button type='button'>send param</button>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.querySelector('button').onclick
    = () => window.location.href
    = 'destination.html?nameOfParam='
    + encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[type=text]').value)
  </script>
</body>
```

You can do this with PHP, which is more realistic and practical.

```
<body>
  <form action='destination.php' method='get'>
    <input name='param' type='text' value='defaultParamValue>
    <input type='submit'>
  </form>
</body>
```

And this is how you retrieve the value with PHP at `destination.php`.

```
$_POST['param'];
```

Here is how to do it with your own example.

```
<body>
  The on/off button:
  <!-- you need to include type='button', otherwise it acts as type='submit' -->
  <button type='button' onclick='press_button()'>
    <img id='button' src='on.png' style='width:100px'>
  </button>
  <BR>
  The button that opens a new webpage:
  <!-- you need to include type='button', otherwise it acts as type='submit' -->
  <button type='button' onclick='confirm()'> Confirm</button>

  <script type='text/javascript'> // the language attribute is deprecated
    var
      i=0,
      button=document.querySelector('button'),
      status
    function press_button(){
      i++
      if(i%2 == 1){
        button.src='off.png'
        status=true
      }
      else{ // you were missing a curly bracket
        button.src='on.png'
        status=false
      }
    } // you were missing a closing curly bracket
    function confirm(){
      if(status){
        // window in window.open is a global variable
        // which means it is always accessible
        // and you do not need to include it
        open(`confirm.html?status=${encodeURIComponent(status)}`)
      }
    } // you were missing a closing curly bracket
  </script>
</body>
```

Structuring your code makes it easier to spot issues (i.e. missing curly brackets) in your code.

The following JS will allow you to obtain the URL query string parameters on the new page.

```
const
  urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search),
  myParam = urlParams.get('status')
console.log(urlParams) // status=true/false
console.log(myParam) // true/false
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using forms to receive the data though. Is there a way to just retrieve variable values only?

Comment: @DarrenWong The JS example doesn't use a form. You really don't even need to use the `input` element if you don't want to. It was simply an example to show you how it's done. Anyways, modified your own code and added it to my answer.

Comment: Sorry there, was busy with exams. I got a day off and now can finally test it out. Brb and sorry again

Comment: @DarrenWong understandable. r u studying CS? im going to bed now but ill check back tomo morn

Comment: I'm currently in the middle of exams but there's a day off inbetween. nayways quick question: Can I just call the variable there in the child page? something like if(status=true){document.write("on")}

Comment: Also fyi, my timezone is GMT+8 so I may not respond for a while. (Currently around 2 pm here)

Comment: @DarrenWong ive added more info to my answer

Comment: sorry, kinda busy now. I'll try and check tomorrow. Thanks for helping me after all this time. You don't have to reply ASAP since it'll be a while before I test the code again. Thanks again!

Comment: @DarrenWong if the answer is useful, vote it up. thats how this site works

Comment: Thanks for being really tolerant, but really sorry, again. Currently not in the mood for my project, exams and all. I might try it in a few days. Until then, you don't have to worry about my situation here.                                                  But quick question: Why is the confirm function an if statement ? Seems a bit weird                                                    And fyi, I left out a lot curly brackets in my actual project code because the image did not change when I clicked on the buttons, only when I deleted some brackets did it actually work. idk how that works.

Comment: @DarrenWong Lol it takes 2 seconds to verify that the answer works... The `if` statement exists to confirm that the user has selected a value/pressed the button at least once

Comment: Ah, I see. Anyway, I'll comment back when I have any more questions. That's gonna take a few days, so sorry for making you wait.

Comment: Yes, terribly sorry. I'll comment back when I've tested it. (at most next week)

Comment: Alright, I'm back, just finished exams and resting, and I've just tested some of the code. Thanks again for your patience with me.

Comment: I've got this in the javascript of confirm.html:                                                                                                     const
  urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search),
  myParam = urlParams.get('status')
console.log(urlParams) // status=true/false
console.log(myParam) // true/false

if (urlParam=true){document.write("selected")}
else{document.write("unselected")}                                                            However it always writes "selected" no matter if the button is on or off. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @DarrenWong im not even sure why your code is working at all since your if/else statement is trying to change the value of a `const` variable... despite that, `urlParams` will always be true. change the condition in your last if/else statement to `if (myParam === 'true') { // do whatever } else if (myParam === 'false') { // do whatever }`

Comment: I've just tried using some checkboxes instead with some CSS decorations as you advised previously, and it was MUCH easier to handle with a php. Man, why did I even use buttons in the first place? Anyway, I'm pretty much done here, thank you SO much for your advice, and sorry for wasting, um, several weeks of your time.

Comment: @DarrenWong lol u still couldnt get the JS to work? anyways, glad i could help. if ur all done select my answer as the answer